# Find two identical cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to set up some kind of check in/out system on Google sheets. So, I'd like to know how long people have been signed in.

Is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY subtract two cells IF and only if these are equal?

For example, subtract time if and only if the names are equal. I'd need to know how long John Doe was signed in for, knowing that other people signed in in-between so I can't assume that names follow each other.

```
 [Timestamp.       Name.          Sign in or out]
 [10:00:00           John Doe          sign in]
 [11:00:00           John Doe          sign out]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if you know how to do this in Excel? I've been looking around and wasn't able to find a solution.

Edit: note that I'd like this to be automatic. Whenever somebody inputs their names twice, it recognizes it, gets the name and the time frame.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Are you looking for built-in functions or for a script? What did you already tried?

Comment: @Rubén yeah I'm not sure how to do this... That's why I came here. I've never written a script before so I was wondering if a formula would work. Sorry if I'm not clear! This is like, a simple check in system like when you check in and out of work? But you need to know how many hours you worked. Other people will sign in so you'd like the sheet to recognize your name and your colleagues names, but the thing is that I would not know the list of names in advance. So I can't use "John Doe" in the formula, since the name could be anything... But I'd like the sheet to recognize when the names match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. If a name has a 'Sign in' and 'Sign out' it calculates the logged in time. It handles the same name 'Sign in and 'Sign out' multiple times. And it will be blank if a name only has a 'Sign in'. Be sure to format the column the formula is placed in as time 00:00:00. Copy the formula down.

```
=if(sumproduct((B2:B=B2)*(C2:C="sign out")*(A2:A))=0,"",if(C2="Sign in",arrayformula(sumproduct((B2:B=B2)*(C2:C="sign out")*(A2:A))-sumproduct((B2:B=B2)*(C2:C="sign in")*(A2:A))),""))
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! I have no idea how you came up with this but it actually works, and it does what I needed! Thank you thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
=sumproduct((B1:B2="John Doe")*(C1:C2="sign out")*(A1:A2))-sumproduct((B1:B2="John Doe")*(C1:C2="sign in")*(A1:A2))
```

that will add up all the sign in and out times, and subtract all the sum of the sign in from the sum of the sign in.  For John Doe.

You may want to do a countifs to see if the count of sign ins is equal to the count of sign outs before processing the above.  The reason being if you so the math with a sign out, you most likely will wind up with negative time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And sorry if I wasn't clear but I'd like to be able to do this without knowing the name before. The name could be John Doe or Barack Obama, or anything else. I'd like the sheet to be able to recognize though, if John Doe signed in and out... See what I mean? Thanks again though, anything helps!